# What is the name for the recursion scheme in which data flows top-down exclusively?

Tags: terminology

This is a question that is in a sense a follow-up of [a question I asked earlier](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/84543/terminology-for-property-of-recursion-definitions), and which was answered.

In that question, the answer to "in which recursion scheme does data only flow bottom up, and in no other way?" was "a catamorphism".

Here, I am looking for the name for (and hence: theory about) the reverse recursion scheme, the one where data flows top-down, and in no other way.

I don't think I am looking for "anamorphism" ... but perhaps there is an error in my thinking. If so, I'd love to hear how. The reason is that an anamorphism is also in a sense a reverse of a catamorphism, but in a different sense than I'm looking for: it's its reverse because rather than collapsing a compound datastructure, it builds one.

As an example of what I'm looking for (in Python), consider the following mechanism that annotates all nodes with their depth:

```
def annotate_with_depth(node, parent_value=-1):
    my_value = parent_value + 1
    children = [annotate_with_depth(child, my_value) for child in node.children]
    return Node(children, my_value)
```

The more generic case of this could be something along these lines:

```
def calculate_depth_from_parent(parent_value, node_):
    return parent_value + 1

def the_generic_thing(mechanism_of_calculation, node, parent_value):
    my_value = mechanism_of_calculation(parent_value, node)

    children = [the_generic_thing(mechanism_of_calculation, child, my_value) for child in node.children]
    return Node(children, my_value)

annotate_with_depth = lambda node: the_generic_thing(calculate_depth_from_parent, node, -1)
```

As a more interesting example, consider the following task: in a directory tree, annotate each directory (of which you know the name) with its full path.